# Why does it yield iron(II) chloride instead of iron when copper meets iron(III) chloride?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals, elements

> Complete the equation:
>
> $$\ce{Cu + FeCl3 -> ? + ?}$$

I wrote $\ce{CuCl2}$ and $\ce{Fe}$, but it turned out to be $\ce{Cu}$ and $\ce{FeCl2}$. I really wonder why.

Comment: Reading this q it looks like a typo was made.  Should the answer be $\ce{CuCl_2}$ and $\ce{FeCl_2}$?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [standard reduction potentials at $\pu{25 ^\circ C}$](http://www5.csudh.edu/oliver/chemdata/data-e.htm):

$$
\begin{array}{clr}
\hline
\text{Reaction} & E^\circ~(\pu{V}) \\
\hline
  \begin{align}
    \ce{Fe^3+ + e- &-> Fe^2+} \\
    \ce{Cu^2+ + 2e- &-> Cu} \\
    \ce{Fe^3+ + 3e- &-> Fe} \\
    \ce{Fe^2+ + 2e- &-> Fe}
  \end{align}
&
  \begin{array}{r}
    +0.77 \\
    +0.34 \\
    -0.04 \\
    -0.41
  \end{array} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

A more positive potential means a greater tendency to be reduced, so $\ce{Cu(II)}$ is easier to reduce to copper metal than either $\ce{Fe(II)}$ or $\ce{Fe(III)}$ being reduced to iron metal. So, copper metal can't force the formation of iron metal.

But $\ce{Fe(III)}$ can be reduced just to $\ce{Fe(II)}$ at a relatively high potential, high enough to allow the copper to be in its oxidized form as $\ce{Cu(II)}$. So, we can have $\ce{Cu(II)}$ and $\ce{Fe(II)}$ at equilibrium and thus we can get the corresponding chlorides $\ce{CuCl2}$, $\ce{FeCl2}$.

Comment: How to get the table in this answer properly aligned?  I tried to get the Reaction and potential columns aligned with spaces but this did not display with my intended alignment.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you comfortable with the edit?

Comment: It should be $E^0$ in table. Otherwise very nice.

Comment: @NilayGhosh Usually the reactions are aligned around arrows $\ce{->}$, and there is no need to use bold math font in header and `\mathrm{...}` for numbers inside `array` environment. Modern tendencies also discourage unnecessary vertical lines in tables.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Would you please explain your edit when you changed the notation $E^\circ$ back to $E^0$?

Comment: @OscarLanzi According to [IUPAC Green Book](https://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/e-resources/ONLINE-IUPAC-GB3-2ndPrinting-Online-Sep2012.pdf), p. 57, only $^⦵$ or $^\circ$ are allowed to denote standard state. Since plimsoll is tricky to get right with $\rm \LaTeX$, `$^\circ$` is commonly used. Putting zero ("$^0$") there is just wrong.

Comment: I was misled by @MaxW.

Comment: Yup my mistake. But geeze, super picky with the markup.

Comment: @MaxW Yes, I am. [*Ordnung muss sein*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnung_muss_sein) :)

Comment: @andselisk - Nope. If you believe in entropy, then disorder rules. ;-)

Comment: @OscarLanzi (sorry for following up on an old post!) When you compare the reduction potential of Cl- ion and Cu, Cl- has a more negative reduction potential, implying Cl- is more readily oxidized to be Cl2. 
I was wondering why we already knew that Cl2 would not be a product?

Comment: Iron (III) is reduced to iron(II) at a potential well below the 1.36 V listed for the chlorine/chloride equilibrium.  The chlorine thus remains reduced.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Why does that happen? Specifically, why does the iron(III) reduction occur if chlorine has a greater reduction potential?